# How to redirect to index instead of show as getting undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using `render 'form'` in `index.html.erb`, and when the user submits the form, he gets taken to /books/1. Instead, I want him to redirect to index controller (so, the /books page).

I have tried to use:

```
format.html { render action: "index", notice: 'Book Created' }
```

In the `index.html.erb` file, I have:

```
<% @books.each_with_index do |book,index| %>
```

That page is giving the error:

```
undefined method each_with_index
```

Here are my methods:

```
def index
  @books = Book.all
  @book = Book.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.json { render json: @books }
  end
end

def create
  @book = current_user.books.new(params[:book])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @book.save
      format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book created.' }
      #format.html { render action: "index", notice: 'Book Created' }      
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

How do I make the form redirect to index page instead of show page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect to index page, you should use `redirect_to` method:

```
def create
  @book = current_user.books.new(params[:book])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @book.save
      format.html { redirect_to action: :index, notice: 'Book created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes I just realized, silly me, thanks, btw the notice is not being shown ? and the url is having /books?notice=Book+updated, is this how it is supposed to be ?

Answer (score 0):

Change to controller_path

```
 def create

  @book = current_user.books.new(params[:book])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @book.save
      format.html { redirect_to tests_path, notice: 'Book created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```